# Minimize paragraph after 100 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paragraph

I have a section of JavaScript that has a variable `ratingtext` that has a value of say 300 characters.

Then I have some jQuery that I have set to minimize the P text and display more or less.

This has been tested on a bulk paragraph text within jsfiddel, however when I try the jQuery at the end of my JavaScript and try to apply the script to my JavaScript it dose display the *more* or *less* `<a>`

**My JavaScript**

```
rating += '<div class="da2-da8"><p class="minimize' + i + '">' + ratingtext + '</p></div>';
$('.ratings').append(rating);
$('img').error(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-t8_QcDAPeX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/CBAXQhe_R-A/w60-h60-p-mo/photo.jpg');
});
```

**My jQuery under the JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var minimized_elements = $('p.minimize');
    minimized_elements.each(function() {
        var t = $(this).text();
        if(t.length < 100) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );

    });

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple fix, after a weekend away I have seen my error strait away

```
rating += '<div class="da2-da8"><p class="minimize">' + ratingtext + '</p></div>';
$('.ratings').append(rating);
$('img').error(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-t8_QcDAPeX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/CBAXQhe_R-A/w60-h60-p-mo/photo.jpg');
});
```

remove ' +1 ' in the id